# Saving to array for plotting - MATLAB/Octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, nested-loops

I'm having a small issue that I've been looking at for ages and can't see how to fix! I have a nested for loop calculating values over incremental distance inside a for loop that increments the time. The code is:

```
    h = 25;
    for t = 0:0.5:2
        t
        eta = a*cos(k*x-w*t)
        i = 1;
        for z = eta:-h               
             u = w * a * ((cosh(k * (h + z)))/sinh(k*h))*sin(w * t);
             du = (a * w * w) * ((cosh(k * (h + z)))/sinh(k * h)) * cos(w * t); 
             F(i) = (0.5 * rho * Cd * D * u * abs(u)) + rho * A * Cm * du
             i++
             plot(F,z)
        end
        %title('Forces')
        %plot(F,z), hold on
        %drawnow;
        %pause(1/20)

    end
```

Ok so a couple of issues (I have gone through many issues but this is it at the moment): 
1) It is not even entering the second for loop. I am trying to increment z from the value calculated for eta at a certain t and calculate F for each z at that and then move back to the first for loop to increment t. I'm not seeing where the issue is? 
2) I want to save the z and F values into an array so that I can plot for each t (to be animated later). Having issues here as well...

I'd really appreciate any advice or if there's anything you can spot to help me with this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you even get this to run in MATLAB? `i++` is not defined in MATLAB syntax. Apart from that, you never define `a` before you proceed to use it in an operation. What editor did you write this in? The MATLAB editor itself would have told you all that...

Comment: check if `eta` value is less than `-25` in second `for` loop, why is the `t` hanging there?

Comment: Sorry this does work, I removed all my variable declarations. I'm using octave so i++ does seem to work in octave

Comment: no the eta value stays in the -1 to 1 range..

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you don't have all the variables defined.("a", "k", "x", "w" are not known).
Secondly you have to change the syntax from `i++` to `i = i + 1;`
You also have to decrement the `z` in the second for loop.
You have do make these changes and your code will run.

In order to save values in an aray, you shoud use this syntax:

```
YourArray = [YourArray, Value(i)]
```

inside your for loop.
Initialize your array `YourArray = [];` before the loop.

Comment: The OP is running the code in Octave where `i++` and `i--` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: when you're saying Value(i), should that be just the i value, yeah?? I realise that sounds like a stupid question

Comment: Also my variables are defined, I just left that part out.. This code does run and was giving me all correct values but wasn't plotting... I'll see can I get back to that version and edit

Comment: @carandrauq `i++` and `i--` is not valid syntax for Matlab, so if the code would have been ran with Matlab, there would have been an error.

Comment: @user3460758 By saying `Value(i)` I was talking about the value for `Value` at each cycle in the for loop. for example in your case, you may save the force value after each cycle like this: `FF = [ FF, F(i)]` where FF represents the array with all your values for the force F until the step `i` of the for cycle

Comment: @user3460758 There is no way we can debug your code if you don't give us all boundary conditions. The most obvious reason why the nested loop would not execute is that maybe eta is bigger than -h. If you want the loop variable to decrement, at least in MATLAB you need to explicitly mention a negative increment like `for eta:-1:-h`.